# Будут ли утечки памяти в данной функции?

Tags: c, функции, память

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
char* prog = "\b";
char c;
char* add(int size, char* str, char adding) {
    char* copy = malloc(size + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) copy[i] = str[i];
    copy[size] = adding;
    return copy;
}
int main() {
    FILE* f = fopen("programm.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0; (c = getc(f)) != EOF; i++) {
        prog = add(i, prog, c);
    }
    fclose(f);
    printf(prog);
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод верный. Но я не уверен что память такое одобрит.

Comment: Если на `malloc` нет парного `free`, то утечки, безусловно, будут.

Comment: а если передавать copy просто size, без увеличений, и после копирования выделять дополнительную память уже для str и переносить в неё copy, с удалением через free

Comment: 1) память не просто не одобрит, а встанет колом, если на каждый символ её реаллокировать; 2) существует функция realloc(); 3) вывод верный только, мягко скажем, в некоторых случаях, т.к. завершающего нуля в строке нет;

Comment: Да тут вся программа — одна большая утечка...

Comment: спасибо, я уже понял. уже всё исправил.
FILE* f = fopen("programm.txt", "r");
str = malloc(size);
for (int i = 0; (c = getc(f)) != EOF; i++) {
    if (i == size) {
        size += 20;
        str = realloc(str, size);
    }
    str[i] = c;
    str[i + 1] = 0;
}
fclose(f);